# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android

Here's my code:

```
public class RT extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    DrawPanel dp;
    private ArrayList<Path> pointsToDraw = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private Paint mPaint;
    Path path;
    private int strokeNumber = 0;
    double strokeLength = 0.0;
    PathMeasure p;
    double s1 = 0.0,s2 = 0.0 ,s3 = 0.0,s4 = 0.0;
    String st1,st2,st3,st4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dp = new DrawPanel(this);
        dp.setOnTouchListener(this);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(30);

        final TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);  
        tv1.setText("Generated Text Goes Here");  
        tv1.setTextSize(30);  
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv1.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        tv1.setId(R.id.TGText);


        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        Button b1 = new Button(this);  
        b1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
        b1.setTextSize(20);  
        b1.setText("Generate");  
        b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        b1.setId(R.id.TGButton);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                p = new PathMeasure(path,false);
                strokeLength = p.getLength();
                tv1.setText("Length of stroke: " + Double.toString(strokeLength) + "stroke number = " + strokeNumber);
                if(strokeNumber == 1){
                    s1 = strokeLength;

                    if(s1 < 150.0)
                        st1 = "S";
                    if(s1 > 150.0 && s1 < 250.0)
                        st1 = "M";
                    if(s1 > 250.0 && s1 < 350.0)
                        st1 = "L";
                    if(s1 > 350.0)
                        st1 = "VL";

                }

                if(strokeNumber == 2){
                    s2 = strokeLength;

                    if(s2 < 150.0)
                        st2 = "S";
                    if(s2 > 150.0 && s2 < 250.0)
                        st2 = "M";
                    if(s2 > 250.0 && s2 < 350.0)
                        st2 = "L";
                    if(s2 > 350.0)
                        st2 = "VL";

                }


                if(strokeNumber == 3){
                    s3 = strokeLength;

                    if(s3< 150.0)
                        st3 = "S";
                    if(s3 > 150.0 && s3 < 250.0)
                        st3 = "M";
                    if(s3 > 250.0 && s3 < 350.0)
                        st3 = "L";
                    if(s3 > 350.0)
                        st3 = "VL";

                }

                if(strokeNumber == 4){
                    s4 = strokeLength;

                    if(s4 < 150.0)
                        st4 = "S";
                    if(s4 > 150.0 && s4 < 250.0)
                        st4 = "M";
                    if(s4 > 250.0 && s4 < 350.0)
                        st4 = "L";
                    if(s4 > 350.0)
                        st4 = "VL";

                }

            }
        });

        ll.addView(b1);

        Button b2 = new Button(this);  
        b2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
        b2.setTextSize(20);  
        b2.setText("Back");  
        b2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        b2.setId(R.id.TBButton);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

        ll.addView(b2);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Match to?");
        alert.setMessage("Match this to which alphabet?");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          String value = input.getText().toString();
          //insertValue(value,st1,st2,st3,st4);
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
          }
        });



        Button b3 = new Button(this);  
        b3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
        b3.setTextSize(20);  
        b3.setText("Store");  
        b3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        b3.setId(R.id.TSButton);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    alert.show();
                    dp.clearCanvas();   
                    tv1.setText(st1 + " " + st2 + " " + st3 + " " + st4);
                    s1 = 0.0f;
                    s2 = 0.0f;
                    s3 = 0.0f;
                    s4 = 0.0f;
                } 
        });

        ll.addView(b3);

        Button b4 = new Button(this);  
        b4.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
        b4.setTextSize(20);  
        b4.setText("Clear");  
        b4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        b4.setId(R.id.TCButton);
        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dp.clearCanvas();
                tv1.setText("");
            }
        });

        ll.addView(b4);




        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);  
        fl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
        fl.addView(dp);  
        fl.addView(tv1);  
        fl.addView(ll);
        setContentView(fl);  

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        dp.pause();
    }

        @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        dp.resume();
    }


    private void insertValue(String alphabet, String stroke1,String stroke2,String stroke3,String stroke4) {
            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(DatabaseHelper.Alpha, alphabet);
            cv.put(DatabaseHelper.s1, stroke1);
            cv.put(DatabaseHelper.s2, stroke2);
            cv.put(DatabaseHelper.s3, stroke3);
            cv.put(DatabaseHelper.s4, stroke4);

            db.insert("capitals", null, cv);
            db.close();
        }





    public class DrawPanel extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

        Thread t = null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isItOk = false ;

        public DrawPanel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            holder = getHolder();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while( isItOk == true){

                if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                    continue;
                }

                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
                c.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
                onDraw(c);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            synchronized(pointsToDraw)
            {
                for (Path path : pointsToDraw) {
                    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
            }
            }
        }

        public void pause(){
            isItOk = false;
            while(true){
                try{
                    t.join();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            t = null;
        }

        public void resume(){
            isItOk = true;  
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();

        }

        public void clearCanvas(){
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            pointsToDraw.clear();
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            strokeNumber = 0;
        }



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        synchronized(pointsToDraw)
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(me.getX(), me.getY());
            //path.lineTo(me.getX(), me.getY());
            pointsToDraw.add(path);
            strokeNumber++;
        }else if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            path.lineTo(me.getX(), me.getY());
        }else if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            //path.lineTo(me.getX(), me.getY());
        }
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       return;
    }


}
```

Here's the log content:

```
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3337)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3188)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:401)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:241)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:353)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:257)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at learn.myandroidapp.hr.HandwritingRecognitionTrainer$5.onClick(HandwritingRecognitionTrainer.java:200)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-19 19:48:19.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1185):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please edit and add a comment that highlights line 200. This is where you exception is coming from. Essentially though your problem is that you are trying to add a child view to a parent, but it already has a parent. Likely you either actually want to add its parent to another parent, or you'll want call removeView on the child first.

Comment: @Tim : the error comes from alert.show(), as the rest of the stacktrace indicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. Thanks to Tim. Here are the corrections:

```
  final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final AlertDialog alertd = alert.create();

        alert.setTitle("Match to?");
        alert.setMessage("Match this to which alphabet?");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          String value = input.getText().toString();
          //insertValue(value,st1,st2,st3,st4);
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
              dialog.cancel();
              alertd.dismiss();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final AlertDialog alertd = alert.create();

        alert.setTitle("Match to?");
        alert.setMessage("Match this to which alphabet?");

        // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        EditText input = new EditText(this);
        if(input.getParent() == null) {
        alert.setView(input);
       } else {
       input = null;
        EditText input = new EditText(this);
         alert.setView(input);
          }

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          String value = input.getText().toString();
          //insertValue(value,st1,st2,st3,st4);
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
              dialog.cancel();
              alertd.dismiss();
          }
        });
```